# VNC server & multiclient in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vnc, vnc-viewer, vnc-server

I want to create an application that acts as a vnc client which is connected to multiple servers at once. First and foremost, how do I access the VNC protocol in vb.net (make a client/server, output the display etc)? Second, how can a single client connect to multiple servers?

Thanks for the help! I take it there are no VncServer or VncClient components in the .net framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A .net vnc client library can be downloaded [here](http://cdot.senecac.on.ca/projects/vncsharp/). There are instructions in the documentation for creating c# and vb.net applications.

Comment: That client library is GPL and can/may therefore not be used when linked with Microsoft runtime libraries. It is only useful with the mono platform.

Comment: True, but the site indicates that other licenses are available. (See the licensing sub-heading on the page I linked to in the answer)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any component in the .net framework which can do this for you. My suggestions:

- Implement one of the VNC protocols yourself in .net
- Encapsulate a vnc client application.

Each time you start a client, it connects to a server, so in order to connect to 2 servers, start 2 clients.